# is there an equivalent to addtab in jface/swt?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

hi i am working on a plugin project using eclipse RCP.

I am designing RCP interfaces and i am looking for an equivalent to 
`jtabbedpane addtab ()`

RCP interfaces are based on jface/swt. 
can anyone help me please ?

Comment: You should probably explain what you want to do without referencing Swing. I haven't used Swing in years and don't remember what addtab does exactly.

Comment: @greg-449 
i am looking for a way to make pop up views from a menu, i want the view already created to pop up in a separate window, i just could make it show on the same window, the rcp views are based on swt and jface.